# convert array of objects to array of list

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array of objects looks like :

```
[
    {
        "Type": "Location",
        "Name": "Water",
    },
    {
        "Type": "Location",
        "Coordinates": [
            {
                "Lat": 57.94182777439993,
                "Long": 79.50404114815193
            },
            {
                "Lat": 31.209277877460135,
                "Long": 78.80122177677728
            },
            {
                "Lat": 31.35950051982242,
                "Long": 105.15694820332524
            },
            {
                "Lat": 58.17432360099434,
                "Long": 105.42050546759074
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Water",
    },
    {
        "Type": "Location",
        "Coordinates": [
            {
                "Lat": 58.72972797827911,
                "Long": 76.90570777266291
            },
            {
                "Lat": 29.54717721331581,
                "Long": 76.37859324413196
            },
            {
                "Lat": 30.460511875130663,
                "Long": 105.19418747049103
            },
            {
                "Lat": 59.71902258556691,
                "Long": 106.7755310560839
            }
        ],
        "Type": "Location",
    }
]
```

Note: Some Object won't be having Coordinates.

Need to convert them to a array of list, which would look like,

```
            [
        [
              [80.2, 114.5],
              [67.8, 118.5],
              [69.8, 209.5],
              [82.8, 212.5],
        ],
    [
              [80.2, 114.5],
              [67.8, 118.5],
              [69.8, 209.5],
              [82.8, 212.5],
            ]
    ]
```

[Lat,Long]

I tried,

```
const arrList = resp.data.data.map((coords) => {
          coords.Coordinates.map((coord) => {
            return [coords.Lat, coords.Long];
          });
        });
        console.log("ArrList:", arrList);
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code Issue fixed**

The issue with your code is that you are pushing your `coord.Lat` and `coord.Long` into a single array. This will generate an array of length 8 as output, with `Lat` and `Long` in alternative positions.

**Fix**:
You should push the `coord.Lat` and `coord.Long` as a single array to your output array.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const arrObj = [
  { "Lat": 68.40928899869893, "Long": 39.548560173006884 },
  { "Lat": 45.35600542155823, "Long": 32.5203664592608 },
  { "Lat": 48.94054322456003, "Long": 102.45089391103468 },
  { "Lat": 70.14969277620159, "Long": 96.8283389400378 }
];

const arrList = [];

arrObj.map((coord) => {
  arrList.push([Number(coord.Lat.toFixed(1)), Number(coord.Long.toFixed(1))]);
});

console.log(arrList);
```

**Better Approach**

`Array.map` is used to construct a new array from an existing one with some update on each node of input array. So just return the `Lat` and `Long` coordinates of each node in an array inside `Array.map`. I have made use of [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) aswell here.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const arrObj = [
  { "Lat": 68.40928899869893, "Long": 39.548560173006884 },
  { "Lat": 45.35600542155823, "Long": 32.5203664592608 },
  { "Lat": 48.94054322456003, "Long": 102.45089391103468 },
  { "Lat": 70.14969277620159, "Long": 96.8283389400378 }
];
const arrList = arrObj.map(({Lat, Long}) => ([Number(Lat.toFixed(1)), Number(Long.toFixed(1))]));
console.log(arrList);
```

**Please note** I have added `Number(Lat.toFixed(1))`for the `Lat` and `Long` coordinates. This is to round the floating point number into 1 decimal places and converting it again back to a number.

**Edit**

If you have multiple objects in the array, and you need to return the defined coordinates combination, you can make use for `Array.reduce` along with `Array.map`. Loop through the list using `Array.reduce`, if `Coordinates` is defined, return the list of coordinates using `Array.map`. Push this list to accumulator.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Type": "Location",
    "Name": "Water",
  },
  {
    "Type": "Location",
    "Coordinates": [
      {
        "Lat": 57.94182777439993,
        "Long": 79.50404114815193
      },
      {
        "Lat": 31.209277877460135,
        "Long": 78.80122177677728
      },
      {
        "Lat": 31.35950051982242,
        "Long": 105.15694820332524
      },
      {
        "Lat": 58.17432360099434,
        "Long": 105.42050546759074
      }
    ],
    "Name": "Water",
  },
  {
    "Type": "Location",
    "Coordinates": [
      {
        "Lat": 58.72972797827911,
        "Long": 76.90570777266291
      },
      {
        "Lat": 29.54717721331581,
        "Long": 76.37859324413196
      },
      {
        "Lat": 30.460511875130663,
        "Long": 105.19418747049103
      },
      {
        "Lat": 59.71902258556691,
        "Long": 106.7755310560839
      }
    ],
    "Type": "Location",
  }
];

const output = data.reduce((accumulator, curr) => {
  if(curr.Coordinates) {
    const data = curr.Coordinates.map(({Lat, Long}) => [Lat, Long]);
    accumulator.push(data)
  };
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Your first one should use `forEach` or a `for..of` loop instead of `map`. Nice pickup on the `toFixed`

Comment: @Phil Thankyou. My first approach was just to fix his code. Thatswhy I went with the same approach mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, And also What if I have multiple objects in the array. I have edited the Question and the code I have tried.

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas updated the answer, please check

Comment: @Nitheesh Thanks It works, but I actually don't need an empty array [] if there isn't Coordinates. I tried removing the :[] and replacing ? with &&  from your but it gives undefined where there is no Coordinates. Any fix to that ?

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas If you dont need the empty data, you can achieve it using `Array.reduce` along with `Array.map`. Place `Array.reduce` on the first level and `Array.map` at the second level. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need your [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback to **return** the new array entry

```js
const arrObj = [{"Lat":68.40928899869893,"Long":39.548560173006884},{"Lat":45.35600542155823,"Long":32.5203664592608},{"Lat":48.94054322456003,"Long":102.45089391103468},{"Lat":70.14969277620159,"Long":96.8283389400378}]

const arrList = arrObj.map(({ Lat, Long }) => [ Lat, Long ])
/* or more verbosely
arrObj.map(coords => {
  return [ coords.Lat, coords.Long ]
})
*/

console.log(arrList)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks, But What if I have multiple objects in the array. I have edited the Question and the code I have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You were close-- you just needed the intermediate array.  Also, you were misusing `.map` like a `.forEach` -- since it returns a new array, you don't need to push to an array outside of the scope.  See below:

```js
const arrObj = [
    {
        "Lat": 68.40928899869893,
        "Long": 39.548560173006884
    },
    {
        "Lat": 45.35600542155823,
        "Long": 32.5203664592608
    },
    {
        "Lat": 48.94054322456003,
        "Long": 102.45089391103468
    },
    {
        "Lat": 70.14969277620159,
        "Long": 96.8283389400378
    }
]


const arrList = arrObj.map((coord) => {
  return [
    coord.Lat,
    coord.Long
  ];
})

console.log(arrList);

console.log(arrList)
```

Comment: Thanks, But What if I have multiple objects in the array. I have edited the Question and the code I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to your problem. You can use `.values` method on an Object to get all the values and then push to an array;

```js
const arrObj = [
    {
        "Lat": 68.40928899869893,
        "Long": 39.548560173006884
    },
    {
        "Lat": 45.35600542155823,
        "Long": 32.5203664592608
    },
    {
        "Lat": 48.94054322456003,
        "Long": 102.45089391103468
    },
    {
        "Lat": 70.14969277620159,
        "Long": 96.8283389400378
    }
]
let array = [];
   
arrObj.map((item)=>{
   array.push(Object.values(item))
})
console.log(array)
```